# TcpClient isn't available in Blend

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, blend

I'm writing a blend application that is supposed to use a TCPClient connection to my server, but on compile time I get `Type or namespace TcpClient does not exist...`, even though I know I'm including the right library (as this code is almost copied straight from my C# windows form client).

I'll probably write it over a normal Socket, but if anyone knows why this doesn't show or how can I make it, it would make my life easier.

Thanks ;)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace CCClient
{
    public partial class CCClient
    {
        public CCConnection Connection = null;

        public CCClient()
        {
            if ((this.Connection = new CCConnection(IPAddress.Parse("-_-"), 9001)) == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not instantiate Client Connection to Server.");
            }
            else
            {
                this.Connection.WriteLine("Role: client");
                this.Connection.WriteLine("Stream: test");
            }
        }
    }

    public class CCConnection
    {
        public TcpClient HostConnection = null;
        public StreamWriter HostWriter = null;
        public StreamReader HostReader = null;

        public CCConnection(IPAddress Host, int Port)
        {
            if (Host == null || Port == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not instantiation CCConnection. Host or Port are invalid.");
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    this.HostConnection = new TcpClient();
                    this.HostConnection.Connect(Host, Port);
                    this.HostWriter = new StreamWriter(this.HostConnection.GetStream());
                    this.HostReader = new StreamReader(this.HostConnection.GetStream());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Could not instantiate CCConnection. Exception encountered.\n" + e.Message);
                }
            }
        }

        public void WriteLine( String Argument )
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Argument))
            {
                this.HostWriter.WriteLine(Argument);
                this.HostWriter.Flush();
                return;
            }
        }

        public String ReadLine()
        {
            return this.HostReader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol and upon investigating, the System.Net.Socket class is only usable asynchronously? Whatthe

Comment: What platform/framework are you targeting? If you are targeting Silverlight, then yes: you'll need to use async

Answer (score 2):

MSDN makes it clear enough that this class is only available on .NET full/client profiles,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx

It is not available in Silverlight or XNA as Microsoft does not think you ever need it.

You may refer to Silverlight articles to see what kind of networking support is provided,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

And probably you can use Socket to achieve the same goal,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.95%29.aspx